# Pass array to Excel

Tags: php, arrays, phpexcel

I am using (trying to use) PHPExcel to pass an array to excel, I have defined the headings and i want every array in the array to in a separate row.

However, this only puts the headings in the excel file and not the data from the array. What am i doing wrong?How can I get this to work?

Script:

```
<?php
$databasehost = "localhost";
$databasename = "dummydata";
$databasetable = "import1";
$databasetable2 = "data1";
$databaseusername ="dummydata";
$databasepassword = "dummydata";


$con = @mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from $databasetable;");

$data = array();

$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     $data[$index] = $row;
     $index++;
}

foreach ($data as $key) {
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$key['latitude'].','.$key['longitude'].'&sensor=true';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $dataReceived = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    //echo '<pre>'; print_r($dataReceived['results']); echo '</pre>';

    $compiled = array();
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($dataReceived['results'] as $value) {
        $compiled[$index] = array(
            'ref' => $key['id']);
            foreach ($value['address_components'] as $value2)
            {
                $compiled[$index][$value2['types'][0]] = $value2['long_name'];
            }
        $index++;
    }
    $sortedData = array();
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($compiled as $value) {
        //echo '<pre>'; print_r($value); echo '</pre>';
        $sortedData[$index] = array(
                'ref' => $value['ref'],
                'lat' => $key['latitude'],
                'long' => $key['longitude'],
                'route' => $value['route'],
                'locality' => $value['locality'], 
                'administrative_area_level_2' => $value['administrative_area_level_2'], 
                'administrative_area_level_1' => $value['administrative_area_level_1'], 
                'country' => $value['country'],
                'postal_code_prefix' => $value['postal_code_prefix'],
                'postal_town' => $value['postal_town'],
                'postal_code' => $value['postal_code'],
                'administrative_area_level_3' => $value['administrative_area_level_3'],
                'street_number' => $value['street_number'],
                'establishment' => $value['establishment'],
            ); 
        $index++;

    }   
    echo '<pre>';print_r($sortedData);echo "</pre>";
    /*$query = mysql_query("INSERT INTO $databasetable2
                ref, lat, long, route, locality, administrative_area_level_2, administrative_area_level_1, country, postal_code_prefix, postal_town)
                VALUES
                ()");*/
}

@mysql_close($con);

/**
 * PHPExcel
 *
 * Copyright (C) 2006 - 2011 PHPExcel
 *
 * This library is free software; you can redistribute it and/or
 * modify it under the terms of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License as published by the Free Software Foundation; either
 * version 2.1 of the License, or (at your option) any later version.
 *
 * This library is distributed in the hope that it will be useful,
 * but WITHOUT ANY WARRANTY; without even the implied warranty of
 * MERCHANTABILITY or FITNESS FOR A PARTICULAR PURPOSE.  See the GNU
 * Lesser General Public License for more details.
 *
 * You should have received a copy of the GNU Lesser General Public
 * License along with this library; if not, write to the Free Software
 * Foundation, Inc., 51 Franklin Street, Fifth Floor, Boston, MA  02110-1301  USA
 *
 * @category   PHPExcel
 * @package    PHPExcel
 * @copyright  Copyright (c) 2006 - 2011 PHPExcel (http://www.codeplex.com/PHPExcel)
 * @license    http://www.gnu.org/licenses/old-licenses/lgpl-2.1.txt    LGPL
 * @version    ##VERSION##, ##DATE##
 */

/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

/** PHPExcel */
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';


// Create new PHPExcel object
//echo date('H:i:s') . " Create new PHPExcel object\n";
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set properties
//echo date('H:i:s') . " Set properties\n";
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Anon")
                             ->setLastModifiedBy("Anon")
                             ->setTitle("Crawler Data");


// Add some data
//echo date('H:i:s') . " Add some data\n";
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
            ->setCellValue('A1', 'ref')
            ->setCellValue('B1', 'latitude')
            ->setCellValue('C1', 'longitude')
            ->setCellValue('D1', 'route')
            ->setCellValue('E1', 'locality')
            ->setCellValue('F1', 'administrative_area_level_2')
            ->setCellValue('G1', 'administrative_area_level_1')
            ->setCellValue('H1', 'country')
            ->setCellValue('I1', 'postal_code_prefix')
            ->setCellValue('J1', 'postal_town')
            ->setCellValue('K1', 'postal_code')
            ->setCellValue('L1', 'administrative_area_level_3')
            ->setCellValue('M1', 'street_number')
            ->setCellValue('N1', 'establishment');


//$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($sortedData, null, 'A2');

// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Save Excel 2007 file
//echo date('H:i:s') . " Write to Excel2007 format\n";

 //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-------- I Change 'Excel2007' to 'Excel5' ------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
 //!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!-------- I Change '.xlsx' to '.xls'              ------!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));


// Echo memory peak usage
//echo date('H:i:s') . " Peak memory usage: " . (memory_get_peak_usage(true) / 1024 / 1024) . " MB\r\n";

// Echo done
//echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";




?>
```

file now looks like:

```
<?php
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php';
date_default_timezone_set('Europe/London');

$databasehost = "localhost";
$databasename = "ryansmur_crawler";
$databasetable = "import1";
$databasetable2 = "data1";
$databaseusername ="ryansmur_admin";
$databasepassword = "Penelope1";


$con = @mysql_connect($databasehost,$databaseusername,$databasepassword) or die(mysql_error());
@mysql_select_db($databasename) or die(mysql_error());

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * from $databasetable;");

$data = array();

$index = 0;
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query))
{
     $data[$index] = $row;
     $index++;
}
$headers = array(
    'ref', 'lat', 'long', 'route', 'locality', 'administrative_area_level_2',
    'administrative_area_level_1', 'country', 'postal_code_prefix',
    'postal_town', 'postal_code', 'administrative_area_level_3',
    'street_number', 'establishment',
);
$addRowCreate = function(PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet, $col = 'A', $row = NULL) {
    return function(array $data) use ($sheet, $col, &$row) {
        if ($row === NULL) {
            $row = $sheet->getHighestRow() + 1;
        }
        $sheet->fromArray(array($data), NULL, "$col$row");
        $row++;
    };
};
$doc = new PHPExcel();
$doc->getProperties()->setCreator("Anon")
    ->setLastModifiedBy("Anon")
    ->setTitle("Crawler Data");

$sheet = $doc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet->fromArray($headers);
$addRow = $addRowCreate($sheet);
foreach ($data as $key) {
    $url = 'http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?latlng='.$key['latitude'].','.$key['longitude'].'&sensor=true';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $dataReceived = json_decode($json, TRUE);

    $compiled = array();
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($dataReceived['results'] as $value) {
        $compiled[$index] = array(
            'ref' => $key['id']);
            foreach ($value['address_components'] as $value2)
            {
                $compiled[$index][$value2['types'][0]] = $value2['long_name'];
            }
        $index++;
    }
    $sortedData = array();
    $index = 0;
    foreach ($compiled as $value) {
        $addRow(array(
                'ref' => $value['ref'],
                'lat' => $key['latitude'],
                'long' => $key['longitude'],
                'route' => $value['route'],
                'locality' => $value['locality'], 
                'administrative_area_level_2' => $value['administrative_area_level_2'], 
                'administrative_area_level_1' => $value['administrative_area_level_1'], 
                'country' => $value['country'],
                'postal_code_prefix' => $value['postal_code_prefix'],
                'postal_town' => $value['postal_town'],
                'postal_code' => $value['postal_code'],
                'administrative_area_level_3' => $value['administrative_area_level_3'],
                'street_number' => $value['street_number'],
                'establishment' => $value['establishment'],
            )); 
        $index++;
    }   
}

@mysql_close($con);


$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save(str_replace('.php', '.xls', __FILE__));

echo date('H:i:s') . " Done writing file.\r\n";
?>
```

Comment: Nothing obviously, but with only two lines of code it's difficult to say. Are you sure $sortedArray contains what you believe?

Comment: Much as I'd like to try and claim the bounty.... I can't provide an answer unless you can provide a bit more code, or a definitive var_dump of $sortedArray as I'd asked 2 days ago

Comment: this is a print_r dump of the array

Comment: If that's a var_dump() then I'm stumped.... it's clearly a fault in PHPExcel, but I doubt if I'll ever be able to replicate it so I'm unlikely ever to be able to fix it

Comment: Looking closely at your array, it's actually two arrays: can you provide a var_dump() of $sortedArray because I can then inject it directly into a test script to step through in debug

Comment: this is a link to the print_r http://www.ryansmurphy.com/crawler/get-data.php of the array

Comment: That's what I thought, this is not one dump, but multiple dumps from multiple arrays, not from one array, including a whole host of empty arrays.... which of these is $sortedData at the point where you're passing it to the fromArray() function?

Comment: its all generated from this:echo '<pre>';print_r($sortedData);echo "</pre>";

Comment: So how many times is this called? And where is it called in your code snippet? I don't see any looping in your code at all

Comment: its only called once. its just before the bit where I parse it into fromArray().

Comment: Then how can you explain the multiple array dumps? The output in your link points me to a whole series of dumps, not just one... I think you're executing this code multiple times, saving the PHPExcel object each time (overwriting the previous save) and the last $sortedData dump in your link is an empty array, which would explain the empty file

Comment: I have posted my script

Comment: As I suspected, you're executing the dump in the `foreach ($data as $key) {` loop, and resetting the $sortedData array each iteration of the loop, and only writing the data to Excel from the last iteration (wich is an empty array).

Comment: You need to extend $sortedArray() each iteration rather than clear it and build it with only the data from that iteration

Comment: can you write it in an answer please?

Comment: I think hakre's answer sums things up pretty well, and gives you a fairly clean solution

Comment: i think i have made the array better, check the link again and let me know what you think? however, its still not going into the excel file

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just re-reading your code and it looks rather chaotic. I think it can be improved in many areas, however with the *least* changes I suggest you do the following:

Instead of first creating multiple arrays of rows you want to add, add a new row each time you have created it. For that you do not even need to name the keys. So *before* you iterate through the database results, first create the headers (I named it `$headers`):

```
$headers = array(
    'ref', 'lat', 'long', 'route', 'locality', 'administrative_area_level_2',
    'administrative_area_level_1', 'country', 'postal_code_prefix',
    'postal_town', 'postal_code', 'administrative_area_level_3',
    'street_number', 'establishment',
);
```

Also before the database iteration, create a helper-function:

```
$addRowCreate = function(PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet, $col = 'A', $row = NULL) {
    return function(array $data) use ($sheet, $col, &$row) {
        if ($row === NULL) {
            $row = $sheet->getHighestRow() + 1;
        }
        $sheet->fromArray(array($data), NULL, "$col$row");
        $row++;
    };
};
```

This `$addRowCreate` helper function will allow you to create a add-row-function later on, like in just a second. Also before the database iteration, create the excel document (memory) and set it's properties. Also add the headers in the first row:

```
$doc = new PHPExcel();
$doc->getProperties()->setCreator("Anon")
    ->setLastModifiedBy("Anon")
    ->setTitle("Crawler Data");

$sheet = $doc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet->fromArray($headers);
```

The next step is to create the add-row-function, which is *very* easy thanks to the helper above:

```
$addRow = $addRowCreate($sheet);
```

You now can use one row after the other by calling it once per row array. For testing purposes, just add another row and save it to disk:

```
$addRow($headers);
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($doc, 'Excel5');
$writer->save(basename(__FILE__, '.php') . '.xls');
die('test finished.');
```

You should now have create the xls file with two rows. You can then remove the test again and *inside* your loops use the `$addRow` function:

```
$addRow(array(
    'ref' => $value['ref'],
    'lat' => $key['latitude'],
    'long' => $key['longitude'],
    'route' => $value['route'],
    'locality' => $value['locality'],
    'administrative_area_level_2' => $value['administrative_area_level_2'],
    'administrative_area_level_1' => $value['administrative_area_level_1'],
    'country' => $value['country'],
    'postal_code_prefix' => $value['postal_code_prefix'],
    'postal_town' => $value['postal_town'],
    'postal_code' => $value['postal_code'],
    'administrative_area_level_3' => $value['administrative_area_level_3'],
    'street_number' => $value['street_number'],
    'establishment' => $value['establishment'],
));
```

Technically you can remove the string-array-keys, however I've kept them in so that you can better find the place where you need to change your code as the array already exists there-in.

After you've put this to the work, you can safely remove all the not-any-more-needed temporary arrays and counters.

The full usage-example (test):

```
require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; /* PHPExcel <http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/> */

$headers = array(
    'ref', 'lat', 'long', 'route', 'locality', 'administrative_area_level_2',
    'administrative_area_level_1', 'country', 'postal_code_prefix',
    'postal_town', 'postal_code', 'administrative_area_level_3',
    'street_number', 'establishment',
);

$addRowCreate = function(PHPExcel_Worksheet $sheet, $col = 'A', $row = NULL) {
    return function(array $data) use ($sheet, $col, &$row) {
        if ($row === NULL) {
            $row = $sheet->getHighestRow() + 1;
        }
        $sheet->fromArray(array($data), NULL, "$col$row");
        $row++;
    };
};

$doc = new PHPExcel();
$doc->getProperties()->setCreator("Anon")
    ->setLastModifiedBy("Anon")
    ->setTitle("Crawler Data");

$sheet = $doc->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
$sheet->fromArray($headers);

$addRow = $addRowCreate($sheet);

$addRow($headers);
$writer = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($doc, 'Excel5');
$writer->save(basename(__FILE__, '.php') . '.xls');
die('test finished.');
```

---

*Old Answer:*

> However, this only puts the headings in the excel file and not the data from the array. What am i doing wrong?

You are actually only storing the headings into the file. You do not store any data.

> How can I get this to work?

Bring the array in the right format and uncomment the following line in your code:

```
//$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->fromArray($sortedData, null, 'A2');
```

Take care that `$sortedData` is the needed 2D array, [see the examples in this dicsussion](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/discussions/77737):

```
Array
(

    [0] => Array
        (
            [0] => Relative CellA1
            [1] => Relative CellB1
            [2] => Relative CellC1
        )
    [1] => Array
        (
            [0] => Relative CellA2
            [1] => Relative CellB2
            [2] => Relative CellC2
        )

)
```

Unless you don't get the array into *that* kind of 2D format, the function will not work in your favor.

Please let me know if you've got any more questions.

Comment: A function returning a function. That is also a so called high-order-function: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higher-order_function - I use it here to keep the lines of code low. Instead one could implement a specific *Method Object*  that has a setter or constructor parameter for the *Sheet* which can be *addRow($array)* then. If you're interested in the details, `$addRow` without a `$row` parameter *only* works if the sheet has one row already.

Comment: i replaced all the content from below require_once 'Classes/PHPExcel.php'; that line with your solution and didnt work.

Comment: @RyanMurphy: Move my code to the very top of all the code you've got in your question. It's meant to be at the beginning. That is meant by *"before you iterate through the database results"*. To not make any errros, insert empty lines *after* `<?php` in line #1 and then put it in there. The `die()` statement from the test should prevent you from executing your code so you first can try if it works for you. -- BTW: You can not use variables earlier than you assign a value to them: http://php.net/variables.basics

Comment: so basically stick it all above me code? and see if it put the array into my spreadsheet?

Comment: @RyanMurphy: Code does not work magically, it *just* works. So you need to place it always on the right place. As you can read in my answer I've been given detailed description where to place what. As you already have misunderstood where to place the first code-block, It's highly likely you should read the answer more carefully regarding where to put what. I suggest you first get the test to run and then you report back if that works (or not). The test works when you see a short message on executing the script and then when you open the XLS file it must contain two identical lines.

Comment: really not sure i get you. you say put the function at the top the add row create which uses the excelworksheetfunction, but the php excel class isnt included until later so it wont be able to reference it.

Answer (score -1):

PHPExcel write data to the cell and you must define it position. Just like then you define headers. The principle is that you fill out the document line by line.
So I write example code to show the idea

```
$alphas = range('A', 'Z'); // A, B, C, D, E...

$sheet = $excel->getActiveSheet();
//headers
$sheet
    ->setCellValue($alphas[0].'1', 'Title1')
    ->setCellValue($alphas[1].'1', 'Title2')
    ->setCellValue($alphas[2].'1', 'Title3')
    ->setCellValue($alphas[3].'1', 'Title4')
;
$sheet->getColumnDimension($alphas[0])->setWidth(40);
$sheet->getColumnDimension($alphas[1])->setWidth(9);
$sheet->getColumnDimension($alphas[2])->setWidth(60);
$sheet->getColumnDimension($alphas[3])->setWidth(30);

$items = ...;// <--- your data
$row_num = 2; // start from 2 row
foreach($items as $item) {
    $sheet->setCellValue($alphas[0].$row_num, $item['key1']);
    $sheet->setCellValue($alphas[1].$row_num, $item['key2']);
    $sheet->setCellValue($alphas[2].$row_num, $item['key3']);
    $sheet->setCellValue($alphas[3].$row_num, $item['key4']);
    $row_num++;
}
```

Comment: PHPExcel does also allow the fromArray() method that Ryan used in his question, which can write values to a whole block of cells in one call rather than having to write each cell individually

Comment: Yes, this function does the same thing. Of course, if you do not need to transform your data.

Comment: Thanks for explaining that to me.... I hadn't realised that this block of code did the same as fromArray()

Comment: So if `fromArray` function does not work, why not try run over array by hand? Maybe this will help find the problem, since the code shown in the question does not contains obvious errors.

Answer (score -1):

You can create a generic function to get excel content from any 2D arrays.

<kbd>PHP</kbd> array2xlsx function

```
/**
 * This function returns xlsx content from an associative array.
 *
 * Warning: one cell = about 1k memory, so this function does not work
 * if your array is too large.
 *
 * @param array $array
 * @param string $title
 * @param string $author
 * @return string
 */
function array2xlsx(array &$array, $title = 'New Document', $author = null)
{
    // Basic checks
    if (count($array) == 0)
    {
        return null;
    }

    // Putting meta-data into a new excel file
    $ex = new PHPExcel();
    $ex->getProperties()->setLastModifiedBy($title);
    $ex->getProperties()->setTitle($title);
    $ex->getProperties()->setSubject($title);
    $ex->getProperties()->setDescription($title);
    $ex->getProperties()->setCreator($author);

    // Select first page on the excel document
    $ex->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
    $sheet = $ex->getActiveSheet();

    // Writes column titles on row 1 (assuming column names are array keys)
    $column_names = array_keys(reset($array));
    foreach ($column_names as $column_number => $column_name)
    {
        $azNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($column_number);
        $sheet->SetCellValue($azNumber . "1", $column_name);
    }

    // Writes document content
    foreach ($array as $row_number => $row)
    {
        foreach (array_values($row) as $column_number => $cell_content)
        {
            // Converts column numbers to alphabetic numbering
            $azNumber = PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex($column_number);
            $sheet->SetCellValue($azNumber . ($row_number + 2), $cell_content);
        }
    }

    // Creates file contents
    $writer = new PHPExcel_Writer_Excel2007($ex);
    ob_start();
    $writer->save("php://output");
    $content = ob_get_contents();
    ob_end_clean();

    return $content;
}
```

And send it directly to your user, by sending proper headers.

<kbd>PHP</kbd> download_send_header function

```
function download_send_headers($filename) {
    header("Pragma: public");
    header("Expires: 0");
    header("Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0");
    header("Content-Type: application/force-download");
    header("Content-Type: application/octet-stream");
    header("Content-Type: application/download");
    header("Content-Disposition: attachment;filename={$filename}");
    header("Content-Transfer-Encoding: binary");
}
```

<kbd>PHP</kbd> Usage example

```
// We simulate your array
$array = array();
for ($i = 0; ($i < 50); $i++)
{
    $array[$i] = array(
            'ref' => "ref {$i}",
            'lat' => "lat {$i}",
            'long' => "long {$i}",
            'route' => "route {$i}",
            'locality' => "locality {$i}",
            'administrative_area_level_2' => "administrative area level 2 {$i}",
            'administrative_area_level_1' => "administrative area level 1 {$i}",
            'country' => "country {$i}",
            'postal_code_prefix' => "postal_code_prefix {$i}",
            'postal_town' => "postal_town {$i}",
            'postal_code' => "postal code {$i}",
            'administrative_area_level_3' => "administrative area level 3 {$i}",
            'street_number' => "street number {$i}",
            'establishment' => "establishment {$i}",
    );
}

// We send headers and excel content from your array
download_send_headers("my_test.xlsx");
echo array2xlsx($array);
```

<kbd>Result</kbd>

[image]

Comment: The OP's problems doesn't actually lie in the PHPExcel code, but in the part of his code where he builds the $sortedData array in the first place

Comment: Yeah. My answer is more an advice for OP, and an answer if we look at the question's title.

Comment: And while it's a good script in a lot of ways, why do you have your own $num2alpha function rather than using PHPExcel's built-in PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex() method?

Comment: But the fact that OP's array is an empty array means addressing the code for building that array rather than any problem in PHPExcel's fromArray() method

Comment: About `PHPExcel_Cell::stringFromColumnIndex()`, just didn't knew. I wrote that script quite quickly, will edit, thanks for pointing that out.